# airflow webserver cpu usage high even when idle

Tags: airflow

I setup airflow instance using [docker compose defined in quickstart](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html#docker-compose-yaml). I switched to a `LocalExecutor` and removed Celery and worker instance. One other change was to increase healthcheck interval to 3600s. Apart from this all default settings. Airflow image version is 2.0.1

This setup on a ec2 t3a.medium instance has an average 20% CPU utilization even when idle, this simply eats up cpu credits. Looking at cpu utilization I see a gunicorn processes popping up regularly. I stopped webserver and the utilization drops to 2%. Is there any configuration change that can be done to lower the cpu usage and what are the tradeoff involved with that?

Webserver logs looks like this.

```
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:09 +0000] [17] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:09 +0000] [17222] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17222)
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:28 +0000] [17] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:28 +0000] [17237] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17237
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:40 +0000] [17] [INFO] Handling signal: ttou
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:40 +0000] [17225] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 17225)
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:59 +0000] [17] [INFO] Handling signal: ttin
airflow-webserver_1  | [2021-04-12 14:21:59 +0000] [17240] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 17240
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

was able to reduce cpu usage by increasing refresh and timeout intervals. Added these environment variables to airflow-webserver service

```
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__WORKER_REFRESH_INTERVAL: 600
AIRFLOW__WEBSERVER__WEB_SERVER_WORKER_TIMEOUT: 1200
```

Comment: FYI `worker_refresh_interval` latest default value of 6000 is already more forgiving than this